# scipy.misc imread returns 2d array of zeroes when reading RGBA image with flatten=True

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library, imread

I'm trying to get a 2d numpy array with grayscale values from RGBA image. The method I use is `imread` from `spicy.misc`, but whenever I set `mode='F'` or `flatten=True` the result is a zero matrix.

My code:

```
img_mat = misc.imread(f, mode='F')
```

also tried

```
img_mat = misc.imread(f, flatten=True)
```

Output:

```
(278, 278)
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

And the image: [letter A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKenZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is "pure alpha"!  The RGB components of the image are all 0; only the alpha channel has nonzero values.  Apparently, when the underlying image library (PIL or Pillow) converts an RGBA image to mode 'F', it ignores the alpha channel, so you end up with an array of zeros.

Instead of flattening the image when you read it, you could read the RGBA data, and then use the alpha channel as your flattened image:

```
img_data = imread(f)         # Read the RGBA image
img_mat = img_data[:, :, 3]  # Extract the alpha channel
```

Comment: Thanks, found that an hour later. Used to get 3 dimensional array as an input for Conv2d layer in Keras `image_mat = misc.imread(f)
        image_mat = image_mat[:, :, 3:] / [1.0]`